# Hide treeview from user

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have web.sitemap for page access, but i want to hide some node from user, that mean only admin can access to this page. I want to hide Report  from user.

```
web.config
<location path="~/Form/Report.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles ="admin" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

web.sitemap
  <siteMapNode url="Form\Report.aspx" title="Report"  description="" roles ="admin">
    </siteMapNode>
```